# userSlice and videoSlice getting updated with the same value

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am attempting backend by following a youtube tutorial for a project. I have this error with Redux which i am not able to figure out for hours. currentVideo in Video.jsx is undefined because the user and video slice are getting updated with the same currentUser value. I want to know what is the error here and how do i get videoRes.data into currentVideo. I want to create a user store and video store seperately.

Video.jsx file where i am implementing the main logic :

```
export default function Video() {
    const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const { currentVideo } = useSelector((state) => state.video);
  
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const path = useLocation().pathname.split("/")[2];

    const [channel, setChannel] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            dispatch(fetchStart());
        try {
            const videoRes = await axios.get(`/videos/find/${path}`);
            const channelRes = await axios.get(`/users/find/${videoRes.data.userId}`);
            setChannel(channelRes.data);
            dispatch(fetchSuccess(videoRes.data));
            

        } catch (err) { dispatch(fetchFailure())}
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [path, dispatch]);
  
  
    
    console.log(currentUser); 
    console.log(currentVideo); // here I'm getting the value undefined
  return (<></>)
}
```

videoSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  currentVideo: {},
  loading: false,
  error: false,
};

export const videoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "video",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchStart: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    fetchSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.currentVideo = action.payload;
    
    },
    fetchFailure: (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
    
  },
});

export const { fetchStart, fetchSuccess, fetchFailure } = videoSlice.actions;
export default videoSlice.reducer;
```

userSlice.jsx

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  loading: false, 
  error: false
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginStart: (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
    }, 
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.currentUser = action.payload;
    }, 
    loginFailure: (state) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = true;
    }, 
    logout: (state) => {
        state.currentUser = null;
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = false;
    },
  },
})

export const {loginStart, loginFailure, loginSuccess, logout} = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

[Redux Devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drByk.png)
[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAeis.png)

Comment: Where is your createReducer code? That's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: Do you see the currentVideo being set in redux devtools or just an empty object?

Comment: Can you please add the `configureStore` call and the import statements in that file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had importing issues in store.js.